# added password field in form not posting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

So I have a form, in which after selecting option in dropdown menu, I want to add password field to form. I am adding it after selecting option with value "private" by the js function.
Here is html code of the form.

```
<form id="eventForm" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned" action="insertDB.php" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="name">Názov</label>
            <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Názov" name="name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="type">Typ udalosti</label>
            <select id="type" class="pure-control-group" onchange="addPassRow(this.selectedIndex);" name="eventType">
                <option value="sports">Šport</option>
                <option value="culture">Kultúra</option>
                <option value="nature">Príroda</option>
                <option value="education">Vzdelávanie</option>
                <option value="private">Súkromné</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="lati">Zemepisná šírka</label>
            <input id="lati" type="text" placeholder="Zemepisná šírka" name="lati" required>
        </div>

        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="long">Zemepisná dĺžka</label>
            <input id="long" type="text" placeholder="Zemepisná dĺžka" name="long" required>
        </div>

        <div class="pure-control-group" id="linkDiv">
            <label for="link">Link</label>
            <input id="link" type="text" placeholder="Link" size="40" name="link" required>
        </div>

        <div class="pure-controls">
            <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and here is JS function :

```
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

function addPassRow(index) {
    if (index == 4) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');

        div.className = 'pure-control-group';

        div.innerHTML = ' <div class="pure-control-group" id="passwordDiv">' +
                        '<label id="passwordLabel" for="password">Heslo</label>' +
                        '<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Zadaj heslo">' +
                        '</div>';

        insertAfter(document.getElementById("linkDiv"), div);
    };
```

So this is how I added the password field to form. After selecting dropdown to private, password field appears. But after I filled and submited it, i can obtian all values via `$_POST` except password value, but chrome asks me if i want to save the password. If anyone does have an idea why password value is not posting? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the name attribute of your new field:

replace:

```
div.innerHTML = ' <div class="pure-control-group" id="passwordDiv">' +
  '<label id="passwordLabel" for="password">Heslo</label>' +
  '<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Zadaj heslo">' +
  '</div>';
```

With:

```
div.innerHTML = ' <div class="pure-control-group" id="passwordDiv">' +
  '<label id="passwordLabel" for="password">Heslo</label>' +
  '<input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Zadaj heslo">' +
  '</div>';
```

Comment: Oh, of course, i've been trying to solve it for hour and i didnt notice it. Thanks !